# Getting information from another computer

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to make a program where if it's installed on another computer, I can access files on that computer. Is this possible using java? and if so could anyone possibly point me in the right direction with what class(es) I will need to use apart from BufferedReader and such?

EDIT: I've been told to use the serversocket and socket classes. However, one problem I see is connection. If my computer is the server and I disconnect, how do I make the socket connect with me again without me having control over the socket? Or vice-versa, how can I be assured that I can open the serversocket without control over the other computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send files between Java programs running on separate computers, then use Socket and ServerSocket.  The BufferedReader and Writer classes you seem to already know will help you with reading and writing the files.  The socket classes will help you transport items.

Comment: So in this instance my computer would be the server and theirs would be the socket correct? and when an event happens what kind of stream do you write it to? does the ServerSocket have its own data streaming capabilities?

Comment: The server can be either computer.  There will be one server and possibly many clients so pick which ever computer there should be one of and make it the server.  As for transmission, you can read the file in parts and write the bytes/chars to the OutputStream of the socket or you can read it all into memory (into a byte[] or char[]) and use something like ObjectOutputStream to send it.  Hint: OutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()).  The JavaDoc for ObjectOutputStream should help.

Comment: Okay that explains that very well, thanks. Could you read the edit up above please?

Comment: Read the edit.  The Server socket is like a listener - once it's running your client(s) can connect.  If you shut it down (or your machine) your client(s) will be disconnected.  The client is responsible for trying to connect again if the connection is lost - this is the normal way a client has to operate because disconnections can occur for many reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible.

As you will communicate with that program over network, you'll need something like `java.net.Socket` and co.